# Parent Role id G1 does not exist after importing dump to mysql 5.7

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database

I created a DB dump and imported it to a new AWS RDS instance running MySQL 5.7 everything worked fine except for the admin panel. I could not login and got an error report page from magento. Then I imported the same DB dump to a AWS RDS MySQL 5.6 instance and everything worked fine.

Here is the error log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:34:"Parent Role id 'G1' does not exist";i:1;s:2091:"
#0 /path/to/magento-folder/lib/Zend/Acl.php(160): Zend_Acl_Role_Registry->add(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_User), 'G1')
#1 /path/to/magento-folder/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Acl.php(108): Zend_Acl->addRole(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_User), 'G1')
```

I already tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208696/1016425) but to no avail.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on stackoverflow:

```
UPDATE admin_role SET tree_level = 2 WHERE role_type = "U";
```

Then I cleared my Magento cache and was able to log in successfully.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078474/parent-role-id-g1-does-not-exist-error-message-is-displayed-on-login-as-admi

Comment: Why does everybody suggest to delete sessions together with the cache? Cache is enough. If necessary, clean your browser cookies to reset **your** admin session. But clearing `var/session` logs out **all customers** and deletes guest carts.

Comment: Fair point @fschmengler answer updated

Answer (score -2):

just clean the Magento cache and session from the /var and it will be ok.
worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/74656)

Comment: "clear var/session"? To log out all customers and empty their carts? **Nope.**

Comment: i can show you that it work for me and i found the solutions in other sites.. pls check your comment again. @SiarheyUchukhlebau