# I accidently deleted all the records from magento admin_role , admin_rule , admin_user

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I accidently deleted all the records from magento admin_role , admin_rule , admin_user, i want to login to my magento admin panel. tell me how to re-insert the records. or any solution.[image]

Comment: You can add directly from databse.

Comment: im new to magento ,i dont know can you provide me more details

Comment: Did you try my below answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is custom script to create admin user programmatically.

```
<?php
# Create New admin User programmatically.
require_once(‘./app/Mage.php’);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try {
$user = Mage::getModel(‘admin/user’)
->setData(array(
‘username’  => ‘admin1’,
‘firstname’ => ‘Admin’,
‘lastname’    => ‘Admin’,
’email’     => ‘santosh@test.com’,
‘password’  =>’admin123′,
‘is_active’ => 1
))->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

//Assign Role Id
try {
$user->setRoleIds(array(1))  //Administrator role id is 1 ,Here you can assign other roles ids
->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

echo “User created successfully”;

?>
```

Put the above content in a magento root folder in a file and  then browse the file.

You are done with creating new admin user.

Comment: should i save it as .SQL file, or what

Comment: Make one .php file, save and put it in your root folder. Run it on browser, user will create.

Comment: Works for you ?

Comment: im new to magento , and im building a multivendor store in magento , i dont know anything about magento, i think you are a senior magento developer, can you help me to provide the solution or i can get in touch with you

Comment: i already did, but help me to build up a mutlistore in magento, please

Comment: You can find out your question in stack exchange or add your question.

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:34:"Parent Role id 'G1' does not exist";i:1;s:2159:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Acl.php(160): Zend_Acl_Role_Registry->add(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_User), Array)

Comment: i got this error again

Comment: check this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106578/parent-role-id-g1-does-not-exist-after-importing-dump-to-mysql-5-7

Comment: Run this query to mysql : UPDATE admin_role SET tree_level = 2 WHERE role_type = "U";

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be if you have a backup of your database, so you can import all `admin_*` tables. If you don't have that, You could also fix it by creating a new user with n98-magerun.

If you don't have a database backup and you don't have access to SSH, you could always create a new Magento installation locally or on a different server and copy the `admin_*` table contents from that database.

Last but not least, you could manually create a new user in the database. That would require this piece of MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO `admin_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators');
INSERT INTO `admin_rule` (`rule_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privileges`, `assert_id`, `role_type`, `permission`) VALUES (5, 1, 'all', NULL, 0, 'G', 'allow');
```

After that, you'll have to manually add the user to the database and leave the password field empty. You can then press the "forgot password" link in the admin login page to set a new, working password.

And last but not least: never remove stuff directly from the database again, it will break more than it will fix ;-)

Comment: thanks but can you provide me the admin_user table details

Comment: i mean SQL query to add record

Comment: I'd just open PHPMyAdmin or another tool, so you can add it yourself. That will be the easiest the way to solve that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can add entry directly into the table 'admin_user' or put the below code in a magento root directory and then open file in your browser.

e.g www.yourdomain.com/test.php

```
<?php 
 require_once(‘./app/Mage.php’); 
umask(0);
 Mage::app();
$data = array(
    'username' => 'test_admin',
    'firstname' => 'Your firstname',
     'lastname' => 'Your lastname',
 'email' => 'Your email,
'password' => 'new password',
'is_active' => 1
)

$model = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->setData($data);
$id = $model->save()->getId();
 $model->setRoleIds(array(1))->setRoleUserId($id) ->saveRelations();
echo “Done”; ?>
```